# CSS border radius not displaying correctly on mobile browsers

Tags: mobile, css

The border-radius on my input boxes isn't displaying correctly on mobile browsers (tested on iPhone 4S and iPad 2), although it is on desktop browsers.  I have only added a border radius to the top-left and bottom-left corner, but on the mobile browsers it seems to also be adding a radius to the right corners as well for some reason.

The site is http://fanbeat.com.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: isn't... but not...? please clarify what you mean in that first sentence

Comment: Ah, my bad. The sentenced was supposed to read "The border-radius on my input boxes isn't displaying correctly on mobile browsers (tested on iPhone 4S and iPad 2), although it is on desktop browsers."  I've fixed it above.

Answer (score 0):

you should initial again by yourself firstly, like this

```
border:none;
```